# How do I find the path of a data file in Dancer to use in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, perl, dancer

I have the following Javascript segment:

```
function setLifts() {
     var $lifts = [];
     $.ajax({
          url: 'data/lifts.csv',
          contentType: 'text/csv',
          async: false,
          success: function(text) {
               $lifts = text.split(/\n/);
               return;
          }
     });
     return $lifts;
}
```

I get the following error when I load the page in Chrome: `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/data/lifts.csv 404 (Not Found)`

I have a data directory in the root of my Dancer app. What is the correct path to the csv files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a route handler to deal with those and have Dancer send the file to the client. See the [Dancer doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#send_file).

> Lets the current route handler send a file to the client. Note that
>   the path of the file must be relative to the public directory unless
>   you use the system_path option (see below).
>
> ```
> get '/download/:file' => sub {
>     return send_file(params->{file});
> }
> ```

The directory `data` is not included in a standard Dancer installation. You should move the data to public out of security concerns (the doc talks of `return send_file('/etc/passwd', system_path => 1);`).

Of course stuff in `public` can be downloaded without a route handler. The CSS, JS and `dispatch.fcgi` are in there for starters.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Dancer to tell you best practices I'm afraid. The Dancer support on SO is a little lacking (as are questions in that regard). I suggest you go to irc.perl.org and ask the folks in `#dancer`. They will be happy to explain this stuff to you.